# c# OK to pass "this" to gain higher level access?

Tags: c#, class

I was just wondering if the following is considered OK or if it goes against good programing practices.

```
public class CircuitController   // Library class to get/set controller settings.
{
   ...
   private int numberOfAttachedSensors;   // Number of sensors attached to the controller circuit. I have get/set properties.
   private SensorSettings sensorSettings; // Class to hold the controller's sensor settings and get/set serial methods. I have get property.
   ...

   public CircuitController(SerialPort serialPort, ...)
   {
      ... // Set other fields.
      sensorSettings = new SensorSettings(this);   // Is this considered OK? I use it so that I can access the get property of numberOfAttachedSensors in the SensorSettings class.
      ...
   }
}

public class SensorSettings   // Class to hold the controller's sensor settings and get/set serial methods.
{
   private CircuitController controller; // Set in constructor.

   public SensorSettings(CircuitController controller) {this.controller = controller;}

   public double[] ReturnSensorValues() 
   {
       ...
       double[] resultArray = new double[this.controller.NumberOfSensorsAttachedGetProperty]; // Now I can "look up" to see the current number of sensors.
       ...
    }
}
```

Basically, the most generic controller settings (controller name, is it on/off, etc.) are in the `CircuitController` class but the more specific settings are "grouped" under the `SensorSettings` class. Within `SensorSettings` I sometimes need the state of a higher level setting so this was my solution. I just want to know if this is OK or if there is a more elegant solution.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I simplified things a bit. Basically there is this control circuit that has ~100 serial functions it understands (mixed between getting the controller's settings and setting them). Manually typing out the command strings is a pain so I am working on making a library class which does all the string command assembly for me. But, because there are 100 settings and their respective get/set functions, I didn't want to put them all under the CircuitController class. The controller functions are broken into three catagories: Sensor (multiple) settings, Output settings, and Environment settings. So I created a class for each of these to store the settings and the respective get/set methods which create the proper command string. Unfortunately, there is some cross over. For example, a method under the OutputSettings class uses mostly its own settings but may need one from the Environment class. Hope that makes sense...

Comment: Another option is to use a callback/event, added by CircuitController, to the new SensorSettings. However, it seems sort of silly in this case that it needs to know the number of sensors in the controller ... I would have imagined the sensor (a single reader, no?) to be independent of others.

Comment: @pst: No there are several sensors (and not necessarily independent)  on the circuit which may be swapped at any time. See edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

- Each CircuitController has exactly one SensorSettings "child" which represents the settings shared by all sensors in the circuit.
- Each SensorSettings has exactly one CircuitController "parent".
- The child needs information from the parent and vice versa.

So I'm not sure it makes sense to group out the SensorSettings methods into a separate class at all. There can be good reasons to have objects in a one-to-one relationship, but in this case I'm just not seeing it. Can you elaborate a bit about why you're doing it that way?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is completely correct. The controller circuit has many serial functions spread across three distinct "groups" so I figured that I would "sort" them that way. See my edit.

Comment: Having now read your "Edit", I feel even more strongly that this should all be one class. In your current approach, the properties of a SensorSettings object are *really* properties of the associated CircuitController object, and the nature of your classes requires that they be tightly coupled.

Comment: Well, each sensor (1-12, variable count) can actually have its own settings (one measures distance, another velocity, etc.) but they will always (and only) be used on a controller circuit; same with the output settings (1-8, e.g. output 1 = sensor1output + sensor2output OR output1 = sensor1output). However, the environment settings relate to the to the controller directly (e.g. controller IP address, etc.) so maybe I could/should merge those with the `CircuitController`. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with doing this, assuming that SensorSettings really needs to know the number of sensors (at any given time).

I would suggest passing the CircuitController instance as an interface of some kind. For instance, does ControlSettings REALLY need a CircuitController, or does it need an ISensorCountProvider interface, or an ICircuitController interface?

By using interfaces for things like this, you don't force the classes to rely on each other.

Answer (score 1):

I would try and rethink how you've modelled your classes/abstractions.  Is SensorSettings meant to represent the data for one Sensor, or for many sensors?

If it's for one sensor then it shouldn't ever need the number of sensors, and any logic that operates across many sensors (such as building an array of values) should reside in the Controller class (or whichever class is meant to model a collection of sensors).

If SensorSettings is meant to model a collection of sensors, then the number of sensors should probably be passed into its constructor.

Comment: I updated my original post to add some details. Hopefully it clarifies things a bit.